# Visual Studio adding space after if-statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, formatting, resharper

Sometimes (but not always!?) when I paste or end a line with a semi-colon, Visual Studio will add a space after the `if` statement!  For example, when pasting, this

```
if()
```

will turn into this:

```
if (condition)
```

and, when completing a line, this

```
if(condition)
    DoSomething()
```

will turn into this:

```
if (condition)
    DoSomething();
```

Having to constantly delete this space (sometimes twice!) is driving me absolutely *Bonkers!*  It seems to happen with `if` and `while` but not `for`.

I cannot find anything relating to this in the VS options.  I do have Resharper installed, but it is set to not add the space automatically:
[image: (image of my resharper settings)]

**Why is Visual Studio punishing me?**

Comment: Your formatting preferences look pretty strange to me, but +1 anyway for "Why is Visual Studio punishing me?"

Comment: I've heard that the "if ()" is part of the accepted C# standard, which is quite odd. Can someone verify this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the Visual Studio options, under Text Editor / C# / Formatting / Spacing, in the "Set other spacing options" part, there's an option for "Insert space after keywords in control flow statements".

I *suspect* you'll find you've got that checked, and you don't want it to be. (I have it checked deliberately :)

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 (v17.7.5) is ignoring my "DON'T autoformat" settings and reformatting code when using Ctrl+K,/ to uncomment code.

Answer (score 5):

Disable auto-formatting as you see fit.

> Tools->Options->Text
>   Editor->C#->Formatting->General.

All are checked by default in my C# Express 2010 config:

- Automatically format completed statement on ;
- Automatically format completed block on }
- Automatically format on paste

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio behavior seems to be a little inconsistent here. I tested everything here with the "Automatically Format" settings all checked in the Options, as shown in the following image:

[image]

I used the following code:

```
if(true)
{
   int m = 3;
}
```

If I copy/paste the code above into Visual Studio, Visual Studio will automatically apply formatting - resulting in a space after `if`.

If I type the code in manually, Visual Studio will not automatically add a space after `if`, even after I complete the if line with a closing parenthesis, and even after I complete the if block with a closing bracket.

As mentioned in another answer, if I CTRL+K+D to format the entire document, Visual Studio does insert a space after if.

This is slightly frustrating because if I'm manually writing code I get no space after if (out of habit) but if I paste code or format my document I do get spaces.

Comment: You can always ctl-z after pasting to remove the applied formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant [EditorConfig code style rule option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options) for C# is the following:

```
csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements = false
```

This rule is fully explained on the [C# Formatting Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options#csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements) page.

This allows you to set this option per-project, instead of changing a global option in your Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 0):

Another good trick is leaving the coding as is and hit CTRL+K+D it will auto-format your code and fix the spaces

Comment: Or it will mess up the spaces, if you don't have the settings correct.