# Visual Studio : Automatically insert a space after typing if(

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, coding-style, code-formatting

We have a code style checker that's run before every check-in that requires that C# if statements be formatted like:

```
if (condition)
```

However, my muscle memory has already developed for typing:

```
if(condition)
```

Is there any way to get Visual Studio 2010 to automatically insert that space if I type the if without it? I know you can set it that when you paste code, it will automatically do this, but not while typing. Thanks!

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.
The correct question is: "How do I convince my team to follow a sane coding style (that is a style, which requires the style checker to only allow 'if(condition)' and to explicitly disallow 'if (condition)')?"

Comment: "if (" is the correct way to do it according to the accepted C# coding standards, and most other standards require a space prior to the condition, as it happens. "if(" is plain wrong. Deleting and reinserting the last bracket in your class will format your code correctly for you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Tools` > `Options` > `Text Editor` > `C#` > `Formatting` > `Spacing`

Then check/tick `Insert space after keywords in control flow statements`, which is listed under the `Set other spacing options` sub group.

Win.

Comment: Which spacing option controls this?

Comment: "Insert space after keywords in control flow statements" - it's like, a third of the way down maybe?

Comment: In VS 2015 check  "other spacing options -> insert spaces inside parentheses of control flow statements"

Comment: Excellent. I can't stand when editors decide to do things like this on their own. Always gives issues with git commits.

Comment: VS 2022 and for whatever reason this doesn't work for me. I had to turn off automatic brace completion (C# -> Automatic brace completion) because the only thing that would trigger the reformatting of the if statement was manually typing the closing brace of the if block.

Answer (score 5):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will do this with its default formatting settings. Ctrl+K+D will format the entire document. Thats how I do it. It seems like VS's formatting options may be able to help you, but I have never played with them enough.

Resharper is totally worth it for this and so many other reasons.

Comment: Agreed, only downside is unless you're only working on open source, it's not free (although not overly expensive)

Comment: Yes, I have ReSharper, but I think in this case it's causing the problem... it's automatically inserting the closing brace, thus preventing VS's space fix.... ah well, I can disable that part easily enough.

Answer (score 4):

My VS2010 does it by default after the closing bracket.  Here's the option:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > General > Automatically format completed block on }

and also:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Spacing > Set other spacing options > Insert space after keywords in control flow statements

Comment: Its annoying that it only applies after you type the closing bracket. I believe Resharper is automatically adding the closing bracket, and so the vs formatting is not running. Kinda lame.

Comment: @CMP -- Yes, this appears to be what's happening in my case.

Comment: That is quite lame, although it also seems like the sort of thing that should be configurable in Resharper... in fact, this question appears to have the setting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208231/visual-studio-adding-space-after-if-statements (I don't have Resharper so I can't confirm!)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I think you are looking for Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Spacing -> Set other spacing options -> Insert space after keywords in control flow statements

Answer (score 1):

I have Visual C#, but as I recall it is the same in Studio.

1. Click Tools
2. Click Options
3. Click 'Text Editor' on left menu
4. Click 'C#' on left menu
5. Click 'Formatting' on left menu
6. Make sure all 3 options are checked
   in right area.
7. Click 'Spacing' on left menu
8. Click 'Insert space after keywords
   in control flow statements' in right
   area under the heading of 'Set other
   spacing options'.
9. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting > Spacing
Then select all-> Press CTRL+K+D